# Bellman-ford algorithm for negative cycles explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, bellman-ford

I tried to implement BF algorithm for negative cycle detection.

I followed the lecture [notes](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs545/fall09/ShortestPath2.prn.pdf) to implement algorithm.
My solution was the following:

```
def belman_ford(s, adj, cost):
    arr_len = len(adj)
    dist_arr = [MAX_VAL]*arr_len
    prev_arr = [None]*arr_len
    dist_arr[s] = 0

    for u in range(arr_len):
        for i, v in enumerate(adj[u]):
            if dist_arr[v] == MAX_VAL:
                break
            if dist_arr[v] > dist_arr[u] + cost[u][i]:
                dist_arr[v] = dist_arr[u] + cost[u][i]
                prev_arr[v] = u


    #detect negative cycle
    for u in range(arr_len):
        for i, v in enumerate(adj[u]):
            if dist_arr[v] == MAX_VAL:
                break
            if dist_arr[v] < dist_arr[u] + cost[u][i]:
                return 1

    return 0


def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    #write your code here
    return belman_ford(0,adj, cost)
```

However I found another solution that helped me to pass coding challenge.

```
def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    distance=[0]*len(adj)
    distance[0] = 0
    for ind in range(len(adj)):
        for u in range(len(adj)):
            for v in adj[u]:
                v_index = adj[u].index(v)
                if distance[v] > distance[u] + cost[u][v_index]:
                    distance[v] = distance[u] + cost[u][v_index]
                    if ind==len(adj) - 1:
                        return 1
    return 0
```

I can't understand the logic behind it.
Why actually this `if ind==len(adj) - 1` if statement leads to the cycle detection

As an input I get the adjacency and cost list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the basic idea of Bellman-Ford algorithm, here's some quick review from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm):

> the Bellman–Ford algorithm simply relaxes all the edges, and does this `|V|-1` times, where `|V|` is the number of vertices in the graph.

Then the explanation for your line `if ind==len(adj) - 1` is

> Since the longest possible path without a cycle can be `|V|-1` edges, the edges must be scanned `|V|-1` times to ensure the shortest path has been found for all nodes.
>
> A final scan of all the edges is performed and if any distance is updated, then a path of length `|V|` edges has been found which can only occur if at least one negative cycle exists in the graph.

Bellman-Ford assumes that distances are very large (infinity) at first, then gradually brings them down to the lowest possible. This is called *relaxation*.  In each iteration, the edges one step farther from the source get relaxed.

`S --> A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F --> G --> H --> I`

Now say you have a graph with no negative cycles. Say it has 10 vertices, you need no more than 9 relaxations to reach (get the shortest path of) the farthest vertex from the source. What if after 9 relaxations you still get improvement? You must have negative cycles in your graph.

The `ind` in your code is a counter. When `ind == len(adj) - 1` it means you have relaxed distances for `|V|` times, which tells the existence of negative cycle(s).

Also check out the third page from last in your own note.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think I got your idea. I was a bit confused why they missed the step of  checking for negative-weight cycles, as it described here for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-negative-cycle-graph-bellman-ford/

Comment: @DanielChepenko It's not skipped compared with the one in your link. They are the same. In the version in your link, the relaxation first runs for `V - 1` times, then a last time. If you merge that last time with the first `V - 1` times, it's the code in your question.

Comment: As a bouns, there're some extra early-abandon tricks in implementing Bellman-Ford algorithm. Say whenever you found the shortest distance from source to itself, i.e. `distance[0]`, becomes bizarrely negative, you could stop and conclude you find a negative cycle. In this way, you may not even need to wait for `|V|` scans.

Comment: Thanks, by the way I noticed that in this implementation they initiate distance with 0 at the first step. Any reason to do that instead of initialising with infinity large values?

Comment: @DanielChepenko Just noticed that line (`distance=[0]*len(adj)`). Weird. Could you please double check that this line is in the code that passes the test cases? If so, what's point of again setting `distance[0] = 0`?